# RemoveRange throws InvalidOperationException in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I get the error:

> The instance of entity type 'Pupil' cannot be tracked because another
>   instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When
>   adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value
>   will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned
>   the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key
>   values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing
>   entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When
>   attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with
>   a given key value is attached to the context.

I would understand this error if I would have retrieved before this instance which is then loaded in the context cache, but I haven`t!!!

```
    var pupilsToDelete = pupilIds.Select(id => new Pupil { Id = id });
    context.RemoveRange(pupilsToDelete.ToList());
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

During runtime pupilIds are all different ids!

why do I get that error?

Comment: Are you 100% sure no `Pupil`s are loaded? Where does `pupilIds` come from? And do you have a fresh context instance?

Comment: Pupils are not loaded from database. I also tried context.entry(new Pupil(id = id).state = state.Deleted and did context.savechanges() like in EF6 but did caused also an exception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove records needs to be track able from the context. So instead of create new collection of  `Pupil`  just reference them from context

```
 var pupilsToDelete = context.Pupils.Where(a => pupilIds.Contains(a.Id)).Select(b => b);
 context.Pupils.RemoveRange(pupilsToDelete);
 await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: That code makes no sense and does not even compile ;-) Replace .Select() with .Where(). Lets start from there.

Comment: why not compile does your table name `Pupils` or not ? from which you are trying to remove entry ?

Comment: yeah I got it, now ok, check now, it was a mistake

Comment: Ok the code worked, but why? Does RemoveRange only remove instances which are tracked?

Comment: in your code you are creating a new collection of Rupils which is not actually from the database instance. You need to get the instance of the record which you want to remove

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand you last comment. Yes its true my pupilsToDelete collection is not from database instance because no context is used to retrieve them. And? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126046/discussion-between-mostafiz-and-pascal).

Comment: Hm... the pupilsToDelte.ToList() is not a good idea because I directly fetch the pupils from database, but I should not.

Comment: yes you can remove it too like `context.Pupils.RemoveRange(pupilsToDelete);`

Comment: then everything will run single time in database

Comment: This answer only works around the issue. It doesn't *explain* it. @Pascal, I'm pretty sure Pupils are attached. Check `context.ChangeTracker.Entries<Pupil>().Count()` before deleting Pupils. Or use `pupilIds.Distinct()` just for sure. It's absolutely recommended to use stub entities for deletions, and it should be possible to do it in your way.

Comment: ok gimme some minutes I try again! Ok Gert the count is ZERO! they are not tracked!

Comment: Then it must be one of the too many bugs in EF core. I can't seem to reproduce it though.

Comment: The tip of Gevorg Narimanyan below did also throw exception. Well until then I stick to RemoveRange from Mostafiz ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to remove records, you need to make sure your ObjectContext is tracking them. Best way to remove items as is answered by @Mostafiz, but you can also attach your entities to context.

```
var pupilsToDelete = pupilIds.Select(id => new Pupil { Id = id });
foreach(var p in pupilsToDelete )
   context.Attach(p);
context.RemoveRange(pupilsToDelete.ToList());
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Which is not good approach․

Comment: Btw. there exist a context.AttachRange(pupilsToDelete)... When I run your code I get an exception at RemoveRange...seems I run into a bug here...

Comment: I never tried but heard that it's slow. And in Entity framework documentation you can read RemoveRange function description an how they suggest to use it. Also Attaching can't be better because anyway it need to find all ids.

Comment: context.AttachRange(pupilsToDelete) is also trowing bug?

Comment: Yes it does throw exception!